# How to normalise a vector with thrust?

Tags: normalization, thrust

I am learning the thrust for the moment. I have a question: how to normalise with thrust?
I have a code that works, but I want to know if this is the optimum method.

```
struct square
{
__host__ __device__
float operator() (float x)
{
    return x * x;
}
};




thrust::device_vector<float> d_x(2);
thrust::device_vector<float> d_y(2);
thrust::device_vector<float> d_z(2);
d_x[0] = 3;
d_x[1] = 4;
square<float>        unary_op;
thrust::plus<float> binary_op;
 float init = 0;

// compute norm
float norm = std::sqrt( thrust::transform_reduce(d_x.begin(), d_x.end(), unary_op, init, binary_op) );
thrust::fill(d_y.begin(), d_y.end(), 1/norm);
thrust::transform(d_x.begin(), d_x.end(), d_y.begin(), d_z.begin(), thrust::multiplies<float>());
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be more efficient because it does not need to use for storage or bandwidth for `d_y` or `d_z`:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_x(2);
  d_x[0] = 3;
  d_x[1] = 4;

  float norm = std::sqrt(thrust::inner_product(d_x.begin(), d_x.end()));

  using namespace thrust::placeholders;
  thrust::transform(d_x.begin(), d_x.end(), d_x.begin(), _1 /= norm);

  return 0;
}
```

You'll want to make your problem size a few orders of magnitude larger, of course.